# Why is my javascript binary search erring?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I wrote a binary search in javascript.

```
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function(find) {
  var low = 0, high = this.length - 1,
      i;
  while (low <= high) {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (this[i] > find) { low = i; continue; };
    if (this[i] < find) { high = i; continue; };
    return i;
  }
  return null;
}
```

It fails though to find 5 in my array of integers.

```
var intArray = [1, 2, 3, 5]

if (intArray.binarySearch(5))
  alert("found!");
else 
  alert("no found!");
```

Here is a Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/3uPUF/3/

Comment: in the fiddle, you're missing the `this` from `this[i]`

Comment: oh thank you. I had not noticed that.

Comment: Also, why do I have to define the method with `Array.prototype.binarySearch`? Why doesn't `Array.binarySearch` work?

Comment: may want to replace `(low + high) / 2` with `low + (high - low) / 2` to avoid overflow

Comment: read cockburn's "good parts" book.  basically, that's where the language looks for these things.  think of `Array` as just a function that makes new arrays; the new arrays delegate to `Array.prototype` and not to `Array`.  that's just how it works.

Comment: if ```i``` is not used outside the loop, should declare it inside. Semicolons after the 2 if blocks {} are redundant. Your jsfiddle gives a false negative result if match found at index 0 because in javascript 0 is a 'falsy'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the logic backward for changing low and high, `if this[i] > find` then you want to look between 1 and i-1. `If this[i] < find` then you want to look between i+1 and the length of the array.

Try making these changes:

```
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function(find) {
  var low = 0, high = this.length - 1,
      i;
  while (low <= high) {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (this[i] == find) { return i; }; 
    if (this[i] > find)  { high = i - 1;};
    if (this[i] < find)  { low = i + 1;};
  }
  return null;
}

var intArray = [1, 2, 3, 5]
//index of the element in the array or null if not found    
alert(intArray.binarySearch(5));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparisons are backwards.  If the item that is found at `i` is greater than what you're looking for, then you want to adjust `high`, not `low`.  See my [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMkXV/1/).